# Unsupported connection setting "MVCC" [90113-200] H2 database

Tags: h2

Does anyone know what could be the problem with the connection to the H2 database?
I didn't change anything in my project in terms of database config, and everything worked fine until yesterday.
Now, I cannot run my project locally because the connection craches.

These are the logs from the H2 console:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

H2 1.4.197 was the last version of H2 with `MVCC` setting.

H2 1.4.198 Beta and H2 1.4.199 silently ignore this setting.

H2 1.4.200 and newer versions throw an exception on attempts to use it.

You need to remove `;MVCC=something` from JDBC URL. Please also note that H2 1.4.200 is an old unsupported version of H2 database.